# Kubernetes Ingress on Docker Desktop

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I am trying to use Nginx ingress to access kubernetes dashboard on my local pc. The step I followed are:

Getting nginx ingress

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.48.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Getting kubernetes dashboard

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.2.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

Applying this ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "kubernetes.docker.internal"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:          
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 443
```

Checking that my host file has this line

```
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

If I try to open http://kubernetes.docker.internal/ on my browser I get "Http Error 400 this page isn't working", while on postman I get an error 400 with message "Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server."

How can I resolve?

Answer (score 5):

I resolved adding annotations section in ingress yaml.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard-ingress
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "kubernetes.docker.internal"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:          
            name: kubernetes-dashboard
            port: 
              number: 443
```